# Magento 2 Ui Component in phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, uicomponent, ui-form

I having form in phtml. I need add an multi select component in that form as in admin product edit form( category picker). I dont want external library. Ui component has multi select. How do i use it in my phtml?